Apply styles to shapefiles in GeoNode
I'm currently working in a geo project where so far, an user can upload their own Esri shapefiles from my own site, we save some metadata to our own DB and by hardcoding we use GeoNode 4.2 (with GeoServer 2.23.3) to save the esri shapefiles, and make use of the thumbnail, download, and embedded links that Geonode provides.
GeoNode is running on a Docker container running Ubuntu 22.04, and now I was asked to find a way to apply styles to the shapefiles from our main site, without embedding GeoNode. I was suggested an app called Geostyler, but I can see that this tool provides a SLD file that you manually have to apply to the desired SHP, and my task it's to find a way to provide the user a UI way to stylize a SHP and apply it, all from our own website, and make it as much as easier to the user (for example GeoNode in his own UI provides a tool to stylize each shapefile, but I can't find a way to embed this tool in my own project).
Any suggestions?

via CSS Styles programmatically ? https://doc-geonode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/006_adv_workshop/001_adv_data_mgmt/002_pretty_maps/css.html#styling-with-css
